# Выдача списка с базы данных mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте!
У меня есть база данных, в ней таблица со множеством значений.

Мне необходимо сначало вывести список всех заголовков (вторая ячейка), а если нажать на заголовок, то развернется уже поле для редактирования (третья ячейчка).

Принцип примерно как на livejournal.
Как это можно сделать красиво, возможно с помощью jquery...

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаете div'ку с текстом заголовка. 
На нее вешаете нарямую

```
<div class="hdr" id="header_ID" onClick="reqNexp(ID)">Заголовок</div><div id="edit_ID"></div>
```

или jQuery $('.hdr').click(function(){});

В функции делаете ajax-запрос:

```
$.ajax(
{
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'getcontent.php?id=' + id,
       context: [id],
   success: function(data) {
       $('#edit_' + this[0]).html(data);
   }
   });
```

Запрос вам отдает редактируемое поле (которое ajax'ом пишете на сервер) или форму.

Пробуйте. Поймете общие принципы - сможете очень много разного и красивого делать.

Comment: Почти всё понятно! А что значит "+ id, context: [id]," и "#edit_' + this[0]"? Спасибо :)

Comment: context: это то, что во внутреннней функции будет видно как this

Чтоб не мучаться с конвертацией (jQuery вернет свой объект) мы ложим в массив [id], а потом берем первый элемент this[0]